# Strange output for simple php mysql search

Tags: php, mysql, search

I am trying to Build a simple search that first grabbs 'query' from a form passed from a HTML form through the url to this script.  Once I run the script I get the output: Resource id #140Resource id #141Resource id #142.  Why am I getting this output and what does it mean?

Side note I am just using the "echo" as a way to see the output of each variable.

```
<?php 
//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: " .mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("dataBase") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$user_id = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());
echo $user_id;

$account_id = mysql_query("SELECT 'account_id' FROM accounts_users WHERE 'user_id' LIKE ('$user_id')") or die(mysql_error());
echo $account_id;

$user_name = mysql_query("SELECT 'account_name' FROM accounts WHERE 'id' LIKE ('$account_id')") or die(mysql_error());
echo $user_name;    
?>
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as correct if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the way to print the results. The method `mysql_query` returns a resource that you have to use within a loop to actually print the results. For instance, loop at the second example in the [official doc page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

P.S. `$query = $_GET['query'];` using this statement you could have **Sql injections** problems.

Comment: Thanks helped a lot  And thanks for your concern.  I actually have worked on this problem for a while and rewrote the code many times.  In my last few attempts I didn't bother protecting against injections intill I got the base code to work

Answer (score 1):

Try something similar to this - after first "SELECT" query  :

```
    while($user_id_obj = mysql_fetch_object($user_id))
    {
      echo $user_id_obj->id;
    }
```

- The way you implemented leads to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)
- [SQL Injection Attacks Example](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Comment: Thanks helped a lot  And thanks for your concern.  I actually have worked on this problem for a while and rewrote the code many times.  In my last few attempts I didn't bother protecting against injections intill I got the base code to work

Answer (score 0):

This could be possible in two ways.Which is usefull for you is depends on your requirements.

1.if your query contains a single value as a result then following code with changes in your code will be usefull for you.

```
<?php 
//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: " .mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("dataBase") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$result_user = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());
if (!$result_user) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
$user_id=mysql_result($result_user,0); // outputs first user's id
echo $user_id;
$result_accountuser = mysql_query("SELECT 'account_id' FROM accounts_users WHERE 'user_id' LIKE ('$user_id')") or die(mysql_error());
if (!$result_accountuser) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());
}
$account_id=mysql_result($result_accountuser,0); // outputs first accounts_users's account_id
echo $account_id;
$result_account = mysql_query("SELECT 'account_name' FROM accounts WHERE 'id' LIKE ('$account_id')") or die(mysql_error());
if (!$result_account) {
    die('Could not query:' . mysql_error());

}
echo mysql_result($result_account,0); // outputs first accounts's account_name
?>
```

2.Or your query contains more than one result or more than one rows than following changes in your code will help you

```
<?php 
//connect to database
mysql_connect("localhost", "user", "password") or die("Error connecting to database: " .mysql_error());

mysql_select_db("dataBase") or die(mysql_error());

?>
<?php
$query = $_GET['query']; 
// gets value sent over search form

$result_user = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$query'") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_user))
        {
                $user_id = $row['id'];
                echo    $user_id;
        }


$result_accountuser = mysql_query("SELECT 'account_id' FROM accounts_users WHERE 'user_id' LIKE ('$user_id')") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_accountuser))
        {
                $account_id = $row['account_id'];
                echo $account_id;

        }

$result_account = mysql_query("SELECT 'account_name' FROM accounts WHERE 'id' LIKE ('$account_id')") or die(mysql_error());
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result_account))
        {
                echo $row['account_name'];

        }

?>
```